# How to clone the Linux kernel repository to my machine? I keep geting errors

Tags: windows, github, linux-kernel, repository, git-clone

This is the command I run (in either the Clion, vsc or the Windows terminal):

```sh
git clone https://github.com/torvalds/linux.git
```

And this is what happens:

```auto
Cloning into 'linux'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 9598133, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (136/136), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (73/73), done.
remote: Total 9598133 (delta 70), reused 91 (delta 63), pack-reused 9597997
Receiving objects: 100% (9598133/9598133), 4.31 GiB | 1.37 MiB/s, done.

Resolving deltas: 100% (7876177/7876177), done.
error: invalid path 'drivers/gpu/drm/nouveau/nvkm/subdev/i2c/aux.c'
fatal: unable to checkout working tree
warning: Clone succeeded, but checkout failed.
You can inspect what was checked out with 'git status'
and retry with 'git restore --source=HEAD :/'
```

I have also tried to fork the repository to my GitHub, yet, nothing works. What should I do differently? Why this might not work? How should I go about it? I need to run a shell script related to the commits of the Linux kernel repository. Is there another way to go about it?

Comment: "AUX" (in `aux.c`) is a forbidden name on Windows. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/31976060/7976758 . This repository cannot be checked out in Windows. https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit-clone%5D+error%3A+invalid+path